# How do I add data from one reducer to existing data in the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When a user searches in my ReactJS app he gets results. When the user scrolls I want to load in the next set of data in an infinite scroll using react-waypoint. 
What works is the following:

- loading the initial set of items (and showing them)
- triggering the waypoint scroll
- incrementing the page counter on scroll
- loading the next page with item from the api into nextItems on scroll

What I can't get working is appending this to the existing items.
What I have now is a seperate reducer which loads all the extra data into nextItems. But I want to simply add this to the existing items. I've tried the following in my items.js reducers. But all this does is add an undefined entry to the nextItems array. Somehow I can't wrap my head around this.

```
export function items(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.items;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export function nextItems(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_NEXT_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return [...state.items, ...action.nextItems];

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I have the feeling that I have to combine both reducers and split them on type, or fix this in the item.js actions file. But I don't know how to get this working, and everything I tried got me either confusing errors, or nothing at all.

My actions: https://pastebin.com/zEPsxhb8

My reducers: https://pastebin.com/dSNFFff0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to acheive this with [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
export function nextItems(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_NEXT_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return Object.assign({}, 
                state.items, 
                state.items.concat(action.nextItems)
            );

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was using concat in my component to see what the result would like. The problem is that the state in nextItems is empty. I can't figure out why that is, or where that state is set. Still thanks!

Comment: @Sitethief you should have both actions in the same function and the state should no longer be empty when you add `nextItems`

Comment: Do you mean putting them both in the items reducer and then use the type to get to it? I don't really understand how to get both actions in the same function? Your example is the reducer iirc?

Comment: Found the solution, based on your example. Using a few console.logs I found out that state.items does not exist, and that state represent the items here. Which is logic when you think about it since I placed everything in the items reducer. Since both datasets are arrays, and the return should be an array as well a simple concat of state and action.nextItems was enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my function. For example you can move this function to Utils file or other service.

```
{ ... // this is your reducer 
  return mergeObjectArrays(state, items, options.key || 'id');
}

mergeObjectArrays(arr1, arr2, key = 'id') {
  const res = arr1.slice();

  for (let item of arr2) {
    let index;
    if (typeof key === 'string') {
      index = arr1.findIndex((itm) => itm[key] == item[key]);
    }
    else {
      index = arr1.findIndex((itm) => {
        let eq = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
          eq = eq && itm[key[i]] == item[key[i]]
        }
        return eq;
      });
    }

    if (index === -1) res.push(item);
    else res[index] = item;
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Though the issue is not really how to merge the two arrays but how to get access to both arrays.